# I want to output the connected voice channel to the channel by inputting the user ID

Tags: discord.py

I want to output the connected voice channel to the channel by inputting the user ID.

How do I code it?

I'm using a Google Translator.
Please understand that the translation is strange :)

import discord

Me: !s userID
bot : This user is connecting to the #voicechannel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `member.voice.voice_channel`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def whatchannel(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    channel = member.voice.voice_channel
    if channel is None:
        await bot.say(f"{member.mention} is not connected to voice")
    else:
        await bot.say(f"{member.mention} is connected to {channel.name}")
```